# Using imported modules in more than one file

Tags: python, module, import, reusability

This question is a bit dumb but I have to know it. Is there any way to use imported modules inside other imported modules?

I mean, if I do this:

-main file-

```
import os  
import othermodule  

othermodule.a()
```

-othermodule-

```
def a():
  return os.path.join('/', 'example') # Without reimporting the os module
```

The os module is not recognized by the file. Is there any way to "reuse" the os module?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need to do that, Python only loads modules once (unless you unload them).

But if you really have a situation in which a module can't access the standard library (care to explain???), you can simply access the `os` module within the main module (e.g. `mainfile.os`, modules are just variables when imported into a module namespace).

If the `os` module is already loaded, you can also access it with `sys.modules["os"]`.

Comment: The module can access to the standard library, it was just a question that popped into my mind. Like I said to unholysampler I didn't know that the modules were loaded only once :)

Comment: @Oscar Carballal: Well, that's how I interpreted "The os module is not recognized by the file" ;)

Answer (score 3):

You have to put `import os` in `othermodule.py` as well (or instead, if "main file" doesn't need os itself).  This is a feature; it means `othermodule` doesn't have to care what junk is in "main file".  Python will not read the files for `os` twice, so don't worry about that.

If you need to get at the variables in the main file for some reason, you can do that with `import __main__`, but it's considered a thing to be avoided.

If you need a module to be reread after it's already been imported, you probably should be using `execfile` rather than `import`.

Answer (score 1):

Python only imports a module once. Any subsequent import calls, just access the existing module object.

Comment: Nice! I thought that Python created a new object for every new import call (it would be a mess in big applications). Thanks!